# Rotate UIImageView and make aspect ratio update properly

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, transform, aspect-ratio

I have a UIScrollview, inside this scrollview I have a container UIView that contains an UIImageView (scaleToAspect). I use the scrollview to zoom/pan the container-UIView. It works. The user should also be able to rotate the image, i do this by performing an CGAffineTransform on the ImageView. When transforming the ImageView the bounds are not updated so if starting out in Portrait the image fills up aspect correct to the width with margins on bottom and top. After translation to landscape i get the exact same margins on the sides instead (where there should be no margins” so the image dont fill the full width. How to manage this correctly?

[Before rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsxaM.png)
[After rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61qlU.png)

Comment: Better to post your solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: Do you use constraint for view in scrollView and why do you need this view bacause UIImageView is also a view ?

Comment: @SvetoslavBramchev I need the containerview as zooming is applied with the scrollview on this view while the transformations are done to the child-imageview. this is because otherwise at rotations the view will be clipped with the pre-rotation bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to make bounds of ImageView equal to the frame of the container-UIView that is a direct child to the ScrollView.

```
imageView.bounds = imageView.superview!.frame
```